# Install sql server 2012 on 32 bit from command prompt throwing error for username parameter

Tags: sql-server, command-line

I am trying to install SQL server 2012 using command prompt in a 32 bit environment. These parameters are working well on 64 bit, but on 32 bit it throws an error for user name. I checked, and sql server was installed, but SSMS was not. I need to install sql with SSMS:

```
setup.exe /QS /ACTION=Install /FEATURES=SQL,SSMS /ROLE=""AllFeatures_WithDefaults"" /INSTANCENAME="TestSQL" /INSTANCEID="TestSQL" /INDICATEPROGRESS=""True"" /IAcceptSQLServerLicenseTerms /SQLSVCACCOUNT=""Local Service"" /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS=""BUILTIN\ADMINISTRATORS"" /BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE=""Automatic"" /TCPENABLED=1 /NPENABLED=1 /AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE=""Automatic"" /SKIPRULES=""RebootRequiredCheck"" /SECURITYMODE=SQL /SAPWD="Test135!"
```

Comment: If you share the error message it would go a long way to being able to help.

Comment: Error is parameter name username is missing.